# R: how can one use k-means clustering with fixed initial "means" and fixed size of cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

let's say one has a 9 coordinats for 9 points a,b,c...,i.

Is there any function or solution in R to apply k-means on it with fixed initial "means" and fixed size of cluster, meaning output should be 3 clusters with (a,.,.) (b,.,.) and (c,.,.)?

Answer (score 0):

A distance matrix is useless for k-means.

Maybe you are looking for PAM instead.

Or you just want to assign each object to it's nearest center, i.e. do a 1NN classification?

It's unclear from you question; but if you were actually intending to use k-means, the `kmeans` function has a quite obvious parameter for choosing the initial means...

Comment: After a simple example I understand now why you meant distance matrix is useless while I still can't figure out what PAM is, but thanks for the anwser at first!

Comment: The goal is getting 9 points(coordinats, if this helps) in 3 clusters with 3 points per cluster, where each cluster has a fixed initial starting point. With k-means I can achieve a clustering with 3 clusters, but not every cluster has 3 points since one or more points lying pretty outsides.

Comment: try `?pam`, if I'm not mistaken it is in the base install.
Neither k-means nor pam have a restriction on cluster sizes. The minimize variance (k-means) and distances (pam), but don't allow you to have size constraints.
At laughable 9 points, you could just brute force all combinations.